# Why might this "reboot on ping fail" script not be working?

Tags: networking, bash, cron

I have an unresolved problem with [my vps falling off the network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/748299/15-10-falls-off-network-but-all-services-are-still-up). 
There's no reply and the webhost have no idea, so I thought [this bash script](https://superuser.com/a/378550) should work

```
#!/bin/sh
ping -c5 8.8.8.8
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "ok"
else
    reboot
fi
```

Runs every minute via cron

```
* * * * * /bin/sh /root/pingtest.sh
```

But it's not rebooting when the machine drops off the network - here we can see the syslog showing it losing connection (to the nfs in this case), and the pingtest runs shortly after, but isn't rebooting the machine.

```
May 18 08:58:01 tns CRON[9543]: (root) CMD (/bin/sh /root/pingtest.sh)
May 18 08:58:23 tns kernel: [316511.688142] nfs: server 188.166.172.XX not responding, timed out
May 18 08:59:00 tns kernel: [316548.720075] nfs: server 188.166.172.XX not responding, timed out
May 18 08:59:01 tns CRON[9549]: (root) CMD (/bin/sh /root/pingtest.sh)
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Probably `reboot` (usually `/sbin/reboot`) is not in cron's `PATH`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27452790/bash-reboot-command-not-found
I agree with the above answer, more help in the link here.

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver and javier - of course, that makes sense. I've also added the path to ping, just in case! Thanks.